# Timeouts when checking isomorphisms with igraph

Tags: r, igraph

`withTimeout` function in the `R.utils` package allows interrupting an expression if it takes too long:

```
library(R.utils)
foo1 <- function() {
  print("Tic");
  for (kk in 1:100) {
    print(kk);
    Sys.sleep(0.1);
  }
  print("Tac");
}

withTimeout(foo1(), timeout = 1, onTimeout = "warning")

#[1] "Tic"
#[1] 1
#[1] 2
#[1] 3
#[1] 4
#Warning message:
#In value[[3L]](cond) : time limit reached [cpu=1s, elapsed=1s]
```

However, when computing an isomorphism between two graphs, it does not work:

```
foo2 <- function() {
  print("Tic");
  N <- 10000
  g <- erdos.renyi.game(N, 0.75)
  V(g)$color <- sample(5,N, replace=TRUE)
  is_isomorphic_to(g, g, method='vf2')
  print("Tac");
}

withTimeout(foo2(), timeout = 1, onTimeout = "warning")
```

I read in the documentation of `withTimeout` that:

> More precisely, if a function is implemented in native code (e.g. C)
>   and the developer of that function does not check for user interrupts,
>   then you cannot interrupt that function neither via a user interrupt
>   (e.g. Ctrl-C) nor via the built-in time out mechanism. To change this, you > need to contact the developer of that piece of code and ask them to check 
>   for R user interrupts in their native code.

So, appart from reaching the author, is there some workaround I can do?